# Creating a distance overlay that is computed by the distance of points/lines and recalculated on zooming

Tags: qgis, distance, scale, d3, scale-bar

I created a **fictional map** and visualized it with **d3**. Now I would like to **show a scale/rule** so that the user can see which **distance** (kilometers,meters) he is currently using.

I was thinking about creating lines in **QGIS** (with which I created the map) and than setting the distance in km/m as attributes. After that using these information for the scale on the website.

Is that a good way or is there any easier and better way to do this.

The scale should also change the values when zooming for sure. So a picture is no solution.

Found this here: which is generating distances. But I'm not sure that a can adapt this for me: http://bl.ocks.org/mpmckenna8/def3735b8e1eef5128a7

This one is nearly what I'm looking for: http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/making_a_map.html But I want to create that scalebar on my site and not just as an image. So how to transfer that information?